# Altering start position and insterting string into char array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Is there a way to choose the point in a char array to insert a string without deleting any existing elements of the char array?i.e to insert a string anywhere in the char array

Comment: Arrays are of a fixed size, so you really can't insert anything into them.

Comment: what if they array size is much larger than the string?

Comment: Then you have to manually [move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move_backward) the existing data, and then [copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) the strings data into its place.

Comment: Notice how much easier `std::string::insert` is: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert .  (You would probably use overload #2, 3, or 4 on that page for this.)

Answer (score 2):

No. Arrays don't have methods to insert things into them.

STL containers have such methods. This is one of the many reasons why they are preferred to raw arrays.

If you still need to work with raw array for some reason, you can write a function which does what you need, using additional variable to perform the copy in it. But the returned result will be a *different* array, not your original one.

Comment: how do i index different characters of a string?

Comment: @newprogramer See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/, in particular http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `std::string` from the char array, use the `insert()` method on the string, then convert it back to a char array using the `c_str()` method